# oracle Filter duplicate column values

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the sample data extract i have. And i wanted to delete the duplicate row (last one in this example) as below. I was wondering how can i easily fetch this without that extra record in select query

```
ID   YEAR  CNT   VOLUME  INT_VOLUME  RATE   INT_RATE  GM     GM_RCNT
545  2016   12    5508     5508      1604    1604     0.71   NULL
545  2017   5     1138     2731      824     1977     0.28   -50.42
545  2018   NULL  NULL     -45       2351    NULL     NULL   NULL
626  2016   12    679862   679862    252693  252693   0.63   NULL
626  2017   12    705365   705365    282498  282498   0.6    3.75
626  2018   12    707472   707472    291762  291762   0.59   0.3
626  2018   NULL  NULL     711372    NULL    295186   NULL   NULL --Filter such rows in select
```

Comment: How do *you* define duplicate?  It is not obvious.

Comment: In the above case we have year (2018) coming twice for 626 ID. and I wanted to retain the earlier record. perhaps min(rowid)?

Answer (score 2):

You can choose one year for each `id` using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, year order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This chooses an arbitrary row to keep.  You can adjust the `order by` to refine which row you want to keep.  You can order by `rowid`, but there is no guarantee that it is the "earliest" row.  You need a date or sequence column for that purpose.

Comment: Man no doubt you are GENIUS with 812k reputations..THANK YOU.